# Is it possible to make a number sequence based on a condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First I don't know if it possible but I need something like this

Let's say I have the names in A2 that they repeat themselves so I need to enumerate them on B2 (to write formula here) based on the name for example.

- John Smith
- John Smith
- John Smith
- Jane Doe
- Jane Doe
- Richard Miles
- Mark Loe
- Mark Loe

So I want on B2 a number list based on the name, for example (the number on parentheses should be given by a formula)

- John Smith (1)
- John Smith (2)
- John Smith (3)
- Jane Doe (1)
- Jane Doe (2)
- Richard Miles (1)
- Mark Loe (1)
- Mark Loe (2)

And so on.

Is this possible? Being honest, I've been giving a thought but nothing pops up in my head.

I hope you understood me because I suck at explaining tho.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `B2` use `=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)` and drag down.